# Count fired method

Tags: ios

I have an object that download an image...and when finish the image, a method finishLoad is called to save this image...and i have a list of this object in my UIViewController, i want to know how many times this method is called, and when this count = 10,  i ll call another method. How could i do it?

```
@implementation DownloaderImage
{
    - (void)finishLoad {
//:: hide default image ::
[self setImage:nil];

//:: fade in in loaded picture ::
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
[finalImage setTransform:myTransform];
finalImage.alpha = 1.0;

UIImage *scaledImage = [finalImage.image scaleToSize:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 345.0f)];
finalImage.image = scaledImage;

//:: fade out background picture ::
[backgroundImage setTransform:myTransform];
backgroundImage.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static variable :

```
static int myCount = 0;

- (void)finishLoad
{
    // ...
    myCount++;
    if (myCount == 10)
        // call your method
}
```

Comment: but there are lots of this object, i would count 10 consider all objects in list..not individual i think is like a delegate, when this method fired, i want to count with a static int in my UIViewController

Comment: that the purpose of the static variable, otherwise you use a common instance variable.